# Pattern for database-wrapper in java

Tags: java, constructor, private

I am currently writing a java-class that wraps an SQLite database. This class has two ways to be instantiated:

1. Open an existing database.
2. Create a new database.

This is what I came up with:

```
public class SQLiteDatabaseWrapper {
    public static SQLiteDatabaseWrapper openExisting(File PathToDB) {
        return new SQLiteDatabaseWrapper(PathToDB);
    }

    public static SQLiteDatabaseWrapper createNew(File PathToDB) {
        CreateAndInitializeNewDatabase(PathToDB);
        return new SQLiteDatabaseWrapper(PathToDB);
    }

    private SQLiteDatabaseWrapper(File PathToDB) {
        // Open connection and setup wrapper    
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go in Java, or is there any other best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
public SQLiteDatabaseWrapper(File pathToDB, boolean createNew)
        throws IOException {

    if (!pathToDB.exists()) {
        if (createNew) {
            // Create new database, potentially throws exception
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    // Open connection and setup wrapper
}

public SQLiteDatabaseWrapper(File pathToDB) throws IOException {
    this(pathToDB, false);
}
```

to avoid relying on static methods for creating an instance of your database wrapper.

Comment: I usually do not like `boolean` parameters of this kind. I prefer to have two separate methods for each possible scenario. This reads better.

Comment: Then you've answered your own question. Your static methods are the only reasonable way to have two seperate methods for constructing an object from the same sort of parameters (`File` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: java methods should start lowercase. It's not enforced by the compiler or language spec, but it's a convention that everyone follows, and you'll get into trouble with tools, IDE's, and most importantly other programmers, if you don't follow it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, fixed that.

Comment: +1 because your are right 
-1 because its not an answer to the question and should be a comment :P

Comment: Right, it should have been a comment
Space Cowboy: same goes for local variables!

Answer (score 0):

Java already has standard interfaces for database abstraction called JDBC. The best practice would be to use the existing standard interfaces. Here is a good [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). You should get a SQLite JDBC driver and use that. [SQLite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/) has a [comprehensive list of database drivers including JDBC drivers](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers). Also, here is a [tutorial on connecting to a SQLite database using JDBC](http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectSQLite.do).

Comment: This class does use a JDBC driver. It's main purpose is to provide convenience functions for writing data to the database.

Comment: What do you need to add to the interface that isn't already in JDBC?

Comment: Recognize that by adding a class that accepts a `File` object in the constructor, you've boxed yourself into using only databases that are based on a file on the local system. Most database are *not*. Why not stick to pure JDBC which will facilitate a move to another RDBMS if your application outgrows SQLite?

Comment: What to add: The mapping from objects to database tables is non-trivial. This class handles that. Why code specifically for SQLite? Because it behaves differently than other DBMS in many cases.

Comment: Hove you looked at ORM tools like Hibernate?

Comment: While inventing your own ORM is an excellent learning experience (I've done it several times) and will help you understand existing tools, it's not advised for a production project. Make sure you weigh the choices well!